# How to add padding between two different elements magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

I am trying to separate two elements and create a bit of space between them.
[image: .]

I want there to be a certain amount of space between the Logo and the navbar. Is it possible to do it using default.xml? This is the content of my `defualt.xml` in `Magento_Theme` of my custom theme.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
               template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
</body>
```

If not, what's the way to do it?

Comment: You can apply margin-right on .logo class .It will separate logo and menu items

Answer (score 0):

you can override

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/heade/logo.phtml

file into your local theme

> app/design/frontend/Customtheme/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml

and create one custom CSS class and add with line#18 like

```
<a style="margin-right: 50px" class="logo" href="<?= $block->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $storeName ?>">
```

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

OR

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush